# How can I not be charged for Google Cloud platform project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My colleague created project on my google cloud platform. And after free trial is ended he forgot to cancel projects.

My colleague created a project on my google cloud platform. And after the free trial ended he forgot to cancel projects.

But I did not know that we had to pay for them. We did not use those projects anymore.

Now my debt is 66.58 usd. I did not use those projects. I think my friend is also not used to it. He created them for only tests and he does not know aboud paid subscriptions.

Please help me, I want to use my gmail as a google ads account. But I do not want to pay for a cloud platform. What can I do?

Comment: Despite the fact that documentation [links](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/stackexchange) here, ServerFault is **not Google** support.  The ServerFault community can only help with [on-topic questions](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and can't resolve billing issues, [outages](https://status.cloud.google.com/)  and similar problems. You get what you pay for and when you don't have [a paid support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support) you're mostly on your own. When you do have a paid support plan, please ask questions there: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's clearly a billing issue with Google support, not a specific technical question.

Answer (score 2):

> [I] do not want to pay for cloud platform. What can I do?

Stop using Google Cloud platform, delete your projects and other resources that you're using beyond the [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free).

Consider the amount owed a tuition fee and learn your lesson:

Free trials are only offered because almost universally they won't stay free forever.
Especially when you need a credit card or similar to sign up for a free trial you can be certain that the offer is designed to convert you into becoming a paying customer. And sooner rather than later at that.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the project and all resources will be deleted.

1. Go to **console.cloud.google.com**
2. Select your project (from drop-down on top nav-bar)
3. Select IAM & Admin -> Settings
4. Click on **SHUT DOWN** button on top nav-bar
5. Confirm project shutdown